# what is the right data type for unique key in postgresql DB?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, data-warehouse, sqldatatypes

which data type should I choose for a unique key (id of a user for example) in postgresql database's table?
does bigint is the one?

thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use the `serial` type for automatically incrementing unique ids.

If you plan to have more than two billion entries, use `bigserial`. `serial` is the PostgresSQL equivalent of MySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

[PostgresSQL Documentation: Numeric Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

Comment: I'd recommend against it: if you use `serial` and expose this ID to public via API, then you just made life easy for anyone trying to scrape data from your site.

Comment: if the security of the data depends on the datatype of PK then we have a bigger problem. @PeterKnego

Comment: @RohitNaik sometimes you have public data, but you still do not want to allow scraping all data on your site. For example images or public user profiles. Also, my recommendation is not about datatype, but against serially generating identifiers in a way that can be easily discovered.

Answer (score 8):

`bigint` (or `bigserial` if you need auto-incrementing keys) is just fine.

If **know** for *certain* that you are not going to load too many rows, you might consider `integer` (or a regular `serial`) and potentially save some harddisk space.

Comment: ... and probably some processing power too, at least in 32-bits systems.

Comment: If you plan to have a lot of data there or you may have - use the largest type available. It does happen on real systems/apps sometimes that basic int is exhausted

Answer (score 4):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300741) the current recommended approach to doing auto-increment unique IDs is to use the `generated as identity` syntax instead of `serial`.

Here's an example:

```sql
-- the old way
create table t1 (id serial primary key);

-- the new way
create table t2 (id integer primary key generated always as identity);
```