# Postgres: Unable to set primary key on a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to set primary key on a column (which references a parent table), but I get an error

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches
(
    id serial,
    user_id PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    matched_profile REFERENCES profiles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,  
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_on TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE (user_id, matched_profile)  
);
```

Not sure what's wrong here, if anyone could explain. Thanks!

Comment: you are missing the data type for `user_id` and `matched_profile`

Comment: Btw: the use of `serial` [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)  in favor of standard compliant `identity` columns

Comment: Thanks alot, can you explain what should I use instead of serial? I need a unique identifier for all the rows (maybe in future a use case might come)

Comment: @KaranKumar From the link: *identity columns should be used instead*. Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300370/postgresql-serial-vs-identity).

Comment: It's explained in the link that I included in  my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are missing data types for `user_id` and `matched_profile`.

You are also using serial when you should be using `INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`