# Why is id as SERIAL discontinuous values after failover in RDS Aurora PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I'm testing failover using RDS Aurora PostgreSQL.

First, create RDS Aurora PostgreSQL and access the writer cluster to create users table.

```sh
$ CREATE TABLE users ( 
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
createAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT Now() );
```

And I added one row and checked the table.

```sh
$ INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('test');

$ SELECT * FROM users;
+----+--------+----------------------------+
| id | name   | createdAt                  |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|  1 | test   | 2022-02-02 23:09:57.047981 |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
```

After failover of RDS Aurora Cluster, I added another row and checked the table.

```sh
$ INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('temp');

$ SELECT * FROM users;
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
|  id | name   | createdAt                  |
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
|   1 | test   | 2022-02-01 11:09:57.047981 |
|  32 | temp   | 2022-02-01 11:25:57.047981 |
+-----+--------+----------------------------+
```

After failover, the id value that should be 2 became 32.

Why is this happening?

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: afaik, if you were to create a serial in a transaction and then rollback. And then create a new serial, that rolled back serial is skipped. As if it were taken and then discarded. I guess it has to do with the way serials they are generated.

Comment: @TheFool Thanks I will check that!

Comment: Consider using [identity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300741/4003419) instead of [serial](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial).

Comment: @nari120 Don't worry about it. The only important thing is that IDs need to be **unique**. It doesn't matter if they are strictly sequential or serial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is to be expected. Index modifications are not WAL logged whenever `nextval` is called, because that could become a performance bottleneck. Rather, a WAL record is written every 32 calls. That means that the sequence can skip some values after a crash or failover to the standby.

You may want to read [my ruminations about gaps in sequences](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/).