# Unable to insert table in Postgres due to sequence being out of order

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called person with `primary key` on id;
[image]

[image]

I am trying to insert into this table with:

```
insert into person (first_name, last_name, email, gender, date_of_birth, country_of_birth) values ('Ellissa', 'Gordge', 'ggordge0@gnu.org', 'Male', '2022-03-19', 'Fiji');
```

There should not be any `ID` constraint which are being violated since it is a `BIGSERIAL` yet I am getting this: [image]

It says Key id=(8) already exists and it is incrementing on each attempt to run this command. How can `ID` already exist? And why is it not incrementing from the bottom of the list?

If i specify the id in the insert statement, with a number which i know is unique it works. I just don't understand why is it not doing it automatically since I am using `BIGSERIAL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sequence apparently is out of sync with the values in the column. This can happen when someone did `INSERT INTO person(id, …) VALUES (8, …)` (or maybe a csv `COPY` import, or anything else that did provide values for the `id` column instead of using the default), or when someone did reset the sequence of having inserted data.

<s>You can [alter the sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) to fix this:</s>

```
ALTER SEQUENCE person_id_seq RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM person);
```

You can [set the sequence value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) to fix this:

```
SELECT setval('person_id_seq', MAX(id)+1) FROM person;
```

Also notice that it is [recommended to use an `identity` column rather than a `serial` one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300370/postgresql-serial-vs-identity) to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Its throwing this error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ALTER SEQUENCE person_id_seq RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX(id)+1 ...`  Also could `INCREMENT ` be used here interchanably? Please advise

Comment: Ah, looks like `ALTER SEQUENCE` doesn't support expressions, only hardcoded values like `… RESTART WITH 532;` (you can of course find the maximum manually). Looks like you need to use [the `setval` sequence function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html), similar to Pierre's answer: `SELECT setval('person_id_seq', MAX(id)+1) FROM person;`

Comment: No, `INCREMENT` cannot be used, that's for changing the step of the sequence, e.g. to only odd numbers (`INCREMENT BY 2 START WITH 1`) or decrementing sequences (`INCREMENT BY -1 START WITH 100000`).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'id'), MAX(id)) FROM table_name;
```

This should kickstart your sequence table back in sync, which should fix everything. Make sure to change 'table_name' to the actual name. Cheers!

Comment: This is easier than the accepted answer since you don't have to look up the name of the primary key sequence; you only have to know the table name 