# Postgres violates not null constraint, even when there isn't one

Tags: postgresql

Hey I have a Postgres database that has a Schema with

```
CREATE TABLE Mentor (
    mentor_ID serial unique,
    person_ID serial not null unique,
    career_history varchar(255) not null,
    preferred_communication varchar(50) not null,
    mentoring_preference varchar(50) not null,
    linked_in varchar(100) not null,
    capacity int not null,
    feedback_rating int,
    feeback_comment varchar(255),

    PRIMARY KEY (mentor_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_person FOREIGN KEY (person_ID) REFERENCES Person(person_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Mentee(
    mentee_ID integer not null unique,
    mentor_ID serial references Mentor(mentor_ID),
    person_ID serial not null unique,
    study_year int,
    motivation varchar(50),
    interests varchar(255),
    random_match boolean default false,

    PRIMARY KEY (mentee_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_person FOREIGN KEY  (person_ID) REFERENCES Person(person_ID)
);
```

With this, i expect to be able to enter null values for mentor_ID in my database but when I enter the query

`insert into mentee(mentee_ID, mentor_ID, person_ID) VALUES (12313, null, 1)`

I get the violation

`ERROR:  null value in column "mentor_id" of relation "mentee" violates not-null constraint`

I was wondering how I could make it so I can insert null values for mentor_ID? I dont have it as not null in the table but it still says violating not null constraint.

Thank you

Comment: `SERIAL` implies not null AFAIK. Being more familiar with MySQL I am inclined to say that using `SERIAL` is not appropriate for a foreign key as well but I am unfamiliar with (potential) postgres idioms

Comment: Why do you expect that? You've marked it as the primary key. (Serial has nothing to do with it)

Comment: @RichardHuxton I want to have it so Mentee's may have one or 0 mentors, , how would i reference the Mentor table from Mentee while also giving it the option to still have the entry as null?

Comment: `serial` is the outdated way of defining auto-increment columns. If you really want to stick to that (rather than using the standard-compliant `identity` columns), then **only** use it for primary key columns. The foreign key columns should just be `integer`

Comment: Don't use `serial` for a foreign key column. You don't want values to be generated automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is `not null`.

`serial` is...

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS integer;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

Note the `integer not null`. This is because `serial` is to be used for primary keys, not foreign keys. Foreign keys are always assigned, they don't need to auto increment.

Use a plain `integer`.

```
mentor_ID integer references Mentor(mentor_ID)
```

Same for your other foreign keys.

Notes:

- [identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300370/postgresql-serial-vs-identity) is the SQL standard way to do auto incremented primary keys.
- You don't need to declare primary keys as unique, primary keys are already unique.
- Unless there's a specific reason to constrain the size of a text field, use `text`. `varchar` and `text` only use the necessary amount of space for each row. "foo" will take the same amount of space in `varchar(10)` as in `varchar(255)`. For example, there's no particular reason to limit the size of their linked in nor motivation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So would I be able to reference it if i made mentor_ID into an integer that auto increments using identity and would it then be allowed to be null?

Comment: @othnuk Yes. All the foreign key needs to do is have the same type as what it's referencing: integer. It doesn't care what other constraints are on the primary key, just that the types match.