# ERROR: null value in column "user_id" of relation "order" violates not-null constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, goose

I'm trying to create new table and insert new record but I get an error that tells me that my foreign key is not nullable. But, as I understood, it is not. So here's my record where I try to insert the record:

```sql
create table user_account
(
    user_id      bigserial
        primary key,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tip.order(
    order_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id BIGSERIAL,
    CONSTRAINT "user" FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_schema.user_account(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here's full error:

```
ERROR: null value in column "user_id" of relation "order" violates not-null constraint (SQLSTATE 23502)
```

So I don't understand why is it happening. If you know what can be the problem, please tell me, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Remove all stuff not needed to reproduce the problem. And include tables needed to reproduce.

Comment: @jarlh I removed and added user table

Comment: Seems to work, https://dbfiddle.uk/WJ0410tH

Comment: Or do you mean the INSERT doesn't work? Show how to reproduce.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, I try to insert and it doesn't work here's the insert
INSERT INTO "order"(user_id) values(null);

Comment: `bigserial` is not nullable.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73617248/postgres-violates-not-null-constraint-even-when-there-isnt-one

Comment: Additionally you have another misconception. The [serial declarations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) are **not data types**, but notational  conveniences. Thus using `bigserial` for `order.user_id` is incorrect. That column should be defined as `bigint`.