# What is there difference between Identity vs Generated in Postgres / pgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Given this UI in pgAdmin4, what's the difference between these two options:

- `Identity`
- `Generated`

[image]

I'm from a SQL Server background, so I'm used to setting the `IDENTITY` of an `INT`, for those MSSql tables to auto-generate that column value.

How is this different/similar in Postgres?

What is interesting is when I check out the `GENERATED` option, I get this menu, now?

[image]

While the `IDENTITY` option looks like I need to specify *everything*. So is the difference that `IDENTITY` is very hard-coded specific, while the `GENERATED` is 'let me auto set everything up, except for some expression thingy?'

NOTE: Using the latest Docker image of Postgres, so let's assume v10+ (with regards to `serial` now being off the table in this discussion).

Similar questions:

- [How do I specify that a column should be auto-incremented in pgAdmin?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/265845/1226)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity works the same way as in mssql or SQL in general, PostgreSQL 10+ used `generated as identity` more as a compliant on SQL standard, compared to the older `serial`. I think [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55300741/8032144) explained it well here.
For `GENERATED`, It's a column that will always be created as a computed value from other columns.
Let's say `monthly_salary GENERATED ALWAYS AS (salary/12) STORED`  will use value from `salary` column, calculate, and stored as `monthly_salary`. see [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) here.

For syntax purposes, both are similar. But there is a little difference.\

```
# This one is IDENTITY
GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ] 

# This one is generated from other column
GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( generation_expr ) STORED
```

Comment: AH! awesome - so `GENERATED isn't "I'll _generate_ an auto-incremental value". It's "I'll generate some value based on _existing columns and some other math crap u ask me to do". Where as `IDENTITY` is the auto-incrementing value. Cheers!